# Facebook Graph API - Publicly access Pages info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a JavaScript script that fetches data of a Facebook Page URL and puts it in a form. It works perfectly as long as I am connected to my Facebook Developer Account, and that I use the corresponding App ID.

My question is: can I make this public? Without need to be connected to my Facebook account? I want users on my website to be able to use this feature but I can't figure this out, and I'm now wondering if it's even possible.

This concerns Pages specifically (not Events).

Comment: You either have to make users login to your app (so that you can use their access token to request the data), or you need to move it to the server side, so that you can use either an app or a page access token (both of those should never be exposed in client-side code.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. You can put it as an answer and I'll accept it !

Answer (score 0):

You either have to make users login to your app (so that you can use their access token to request the data),

or you need to move it to the server side, so that you can use either an app or a page access token (both of those should never be exposed in client-side code.)